# How to Call Phtml file in Before Add cart button in Product View Page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to call phtml in product view page.

my XML code is

```
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="booking" before="addtocart"  template="booking/screenseat.phtml"/>
   </reference>
```

but My phtml call after add to cart button

so how Can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="alert.urls">
     <block type="catalog/product_view" name="booking" after="-"  template="booking/screenseat.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This should work.